# install GALib on windows 7

Tags: c++

I'm trying to install this library http://lancet.mit.edu/ga/dist/ on windows 7 using visual studio 2010 but no success.

Each time I get this error msg :

[image]

Is there any help?

Comment: Please just post your error as text in a quote/code box instead of attaching a screenshot. The image is just white for me.

Comment: @JameyD do you still get blank space instead of the screen shot?